# Display Google calendar in application

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to display the Google Calendar UI inside the android app?

I had initially tried integrating the Google Calendar API, but its only showing the events its not showing the whole calendar.  I had created the project in the Google API Console and downloaded the json file and had placed that file inside my project.  I don't know how to bring the calendar please suggest me any code if its possible to bring the Google Calendar.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
private TextView mOutputText;
private Button mCallApiButton;
ProgressDialog mProgress;

static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;

private static final String BUTTON_TEXT = "Call Google Calendar API";
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };

/**
 * Create the main activity.
 * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mCallApiButton = new Button(this);
    mCallApiButton.setText(BUTTON_TEXT);
    mCallApiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallApiButton.setEnabled(false);
            mOutputText.setText("");
            getResultsFromApi();
            mCallApiButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    activityLayout.addView(mCallApiButton);

    mOutputText = new TextView(this);
    mOutputText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    mOutputText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
    mOutputText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mOutputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    mOutputText.setText(
            "Click the \'" + BUTTON_TEXT +"\' button to test the API.");
    activityLayout.addView(mOutputText);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Calendar API ...");

    setContentView(activityLayout);

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
}



/**
 * Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
 * satisfied. The preconditions are: Google Play Services installed, an
 * account was selected and the device currently has online access. If any
 * of the preconditions are not satisfied, the app will prompt the user as
 * appropriate.
 */
private void getResultsFromApi() {
    if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        acquireGooglePlayServices();
    } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
        mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
    } else {
        new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
    }
}

/**
 * Attempts to set the account used with the API credentials. If an account
 * name was previously saved it will use that one; otherwise an account
 * picker dialog will be shown to the user. Note that the setting the
 * account to use with the credentials object requires the app to have the
 * GET_ACCOUNTS permission, which is requested here if it is not already
 * present. The AfterPermissionGranted annotation indicates that this
 * function will be rerun automatically whenever the GET_ACCOUNTS permission
 * is granted.
 */
@AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
private void chooseAccount() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
            this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
        String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        if (accountName != null) {
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            getResultsFromApi();
        } else {
            // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
            startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }
    } else {
        // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
 * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
 * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
 *     activity result.
 * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
 *     activity result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mOutputText.setText(
                        "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                                "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.");
            } else {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Respond to requests for permissions at runtime for API 23 and above.
 * @param requestCode The request code passed in
 *     requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, String, int, String[])
 * @param permissions The requested permissions. Never null.
 * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
 *     which is either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

/**
 * Callback for when a permission is granted using the EasyPermissions
 * library.
 * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
 *         permission
 * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
 */
@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Do nothing.
}

/**
 * Callback for when a permission is denied using the EasyPermissions
 * library.
 * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
 *         permission
 * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
 */
@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Do nothing.
}

/**
 * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
 * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date.
 * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
 *     date on this device; false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
 * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
 */
private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
    }
}


/**
 * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
 * or out of date.
 * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
 *     Google Play Services on this device.
 */
void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
            MainActivity.this,
            connectionStatusCode,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * An asynchronous task that handles the Google Calendar API call.
 * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
 */
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call Google Calendar API.
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
     * @return List of Strings describing returned events.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        for (Event event : items) {
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
            if (start == null) {
                // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                // the start date.
                start = event.getStart().getDate();
            }
            eventStrings.add(
                    String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
        }
        return eventStrings;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mOutputText.setText("");
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
            mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
        } else {
            output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Calendar API:");
            mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (mLastError != null) {
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
            } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                        + mLastError.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google calendar API allows you access to the data within a calendar.  The data is returned in Json format.   It does not display a GUI calendar.

It will be up to you to create a display for your calendar and populate it with the data from Google Calendar

Comment: it is not possible to show the google calendar right

Comment: Unless you want to try and display the Google calendar website into your app no.

Comment: yeah its not possible